# Write Integral in Ostrogradsky's Method Form

Tags: function-construction, integral-equations

Lets say we want to integrate

$$\tag{1}F(x) = \frac{3 x^5-x^4+2 x^3-12 x^2-2 x+1}{\left(x^3-1\right)^2}$$

One approach might be to write it in partial fraction form and then integrate each fraction using the expansion from

```
  Apart[(1-2 x-12 x^2+2 x^3-x^4+3 x^5)/(-1+x^3)^2]
```

Another approach might be to use [*Ostrogradsky's Method*](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Ostrogradski_method#:%7E:text=The%20Ostrogradski%20method%20reduces%20the,transcendental%20functions%3A%20logarithms%20and%20arctangents.) and write $(1)$ as

$$F(x) = \frac{x^2-x+3}{x^3-1} + 3\int \dfrac{x^2}{x^3-1} dx$$

Question: Is there a way to get Mathematica to write (when possible of course) an integral in the form below and to display it in unevaluated form and then to integrate the second part and show?

$$\int \dfrac{P(x)}{Q(x)} = \dfrac{P_1(x)}{Q_1(x)} + \int \dfrac{P_2(x)}{Q_2(x)} dx = \frac{x^2-x+3}{x^3-1} + 3\int \dfrac{x^2}{x^3-1} dx = \dfrac{x^2-x+3}{x^3-1} + \log \left(1-x^3\right)$$

Comment: Video describing this problem and its solution: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mDeASYy-VxA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

ClearAll["Global`*"];

(Format[#[n_Integer]] := Subscript[#, n]) & /@ {P, Q};

$Assumptions = {Q[1][x] != 0, (x^3 - 1)^2 != 0};
```

The original integral is

```
(int1 = Inactive[
    Integrate][(1 - 2 x - 12 x^2 + 2 x^3 - x^4 + 3 x^5)/(-1 + x^3)^2, x])
```

[image]

The numerator of the integrand is

```
p = P[x] == Numerator[int1[[1]]]

(* P[x] == 1 - 2 x - 12 x^2 + 2 x^3 - x^4 + 3 x^5 *)
```

The denominator of the integrand and its derivative are

```
qdq = NestList[D[#, x] &, Q[x] == Denominator[int1[[1]]], 1]

(* {Q[x] == (-1 + x^3)^2, Q'[x] == 6 x^2 (-1 + x^3)} *)

q1 = Q[1][x] == PolynomialGCD @@ qdq[[All, -1]]
```

[image]

```
q2i = DivideSides[qdq[[1]], q1]
```

[image]

```
q2 = ReplacePart[q2i, 1 -> Q[2][x]]
```

[image]

```
{p1, p2} = {P[1][x] == a x^2 + b x + c, P[2][x] == d x^2 + e x + f}
```

[image]

```
p1q1 = DivideSides[p1, q1]
```

[image]

```
p2q2 = DivideSides[p2, q2]
```

[image]

Ostrogradski method form

```
int2i = int1 == P[1][x]/Q[1][x] + Inactive[Integrate][P[2][x]/Q[2][x], x]
```

[image]

```
int2 = int2i /. (Rule @@@ {p1q1, p2q2})
```

[image]

```
eqn1 = D[int2, x]

(* (1 - 2 x - 12 x^2 + 2 x^3 - x^4 + 
  3 x^5)/(-1 + x^3)^2 == -((3 x^2 (c + b x + a x^2))/(-1 + x^3)^2) + (
  b + 2 a x)/(-1 + x^3) + (f + e x + d x^2)/(-1 + x^3) *)

eqn2 = Collect[#, x] & /@ MultiplySides[eqn1, (x^3 - 1)^2] // Simplify

(* 1 + b + f + 2 a x + e x + 3 c x^2 + d x^2 + 2 x^3 + 2 b x^3 + a x^4 + 3 x^5 ==
  x (2 + 12 x + f x^2 + (1 + e) x^3 + d x^4) *)
```

Equating the coefficients,

```
eqns = Thread[CoefficientList[#, x] & /@ eqn2]

(* {1 + b + f == 0, 2 a + e == 2, 3 c + d == 12, 2 + 2 b == f, a == 1 + e, 
 3 == d} *)
```

Solving for the coefficients,

```
coef = Solve[eqns, {a, b, c, d, e, f}][[1]]

(* {a -> 1, b -> -1, c -> 3, d -> 3, e -> 0, f -> 0} *)

int3 = int2 /. coef
```

[image]

The final result is

```
int4 = ReplacePart[int3, -1 :> Activate[int3[[-1]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution, do you think it can be generalized as a Module where you just pass it the function to be integrated and all the steps and intermediate results are displayed?

Comment: That is a good point, I was just looking for alternate methods when the partial fraction expansion is not fun. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Defining a module to perform and display the Ostrogradski method

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

ClearAll["Global`*"];

Ostrogradski::usage = 
  "Ostrogradski[integrand] or Ostrogradski[integrand, variable] displays the \
steps to find the indefinite integral of rational polynomials of either x \
(default) or other specified variable.";

Ostrogradski[integrand_, var : _Symbol : x] :=
 Module[
  {int1, P, Q, omf, p, q, dq, q1, q2, p1,
   p2, aCoef, bCoef, n, a, b, p1q1, repl,
   eqn1, eqn2, sys, coef, sol},
  Format[P[n_Integer]] := Subscript["P", n];
  Format[P[n_]] := StringForm["P(``)", n];
  Format[Q[n_Integer]] := Subscript["Q", n];
  Format[Q[x_]] := StringForm["Q(``)", x];
  Format[Q'[x_]] := StringForm["Q'(``)", x];
  Format[a[n_]] := Subscript["a", n];
  Format[b[n_]] := Subscript["b", n];
  Print[
   {{(int1 =
         Inactive[Integrate][P[var]/Q[var], var] ==
          (omf = P[1][var]/Q[1][var] +
             Inactive[Integrate][P[2][var]/Q[2][var], var])) //
       TraditionalForm, SpanFromLeft},
     {(p = P[var] == Numerator[integrand]) //
       TraditionalForm, SpanFromLeft},
     {(q = Q[var] == Denominator[integrand]) //
       TraditionalForm, ";", Spacer[40],
      (dq = D[q, var]) // TraditionalForm},
     {(q1 = Q[1][var] == GCD[Q[var], Q'[var]] ==
          PolynomialGCD @@ {q, dq}[[All, -1]]) //
       TraditionalForm, SpanFromLeft},
     {(q2 = Q[2][var] == Q[var]/Q[1][var] == q[[-1]]/q1[[-1]]) //
       TraditionalForm, SpanFromLeft},
     {n = Exponent[q1[[-1]], var] - 1;
      (p1 = (P[1][var] == (aCoef = Array[a, n + 1, 0]) . var^Range[0, n])) //
       TraditionalForm, SpanFromLeft},
     {(p2 = (P[2][var] == (bCoef = Array[b, n + 1, 0]) . var^Range[0, n])) //
       TraditionalForm, SpanFromLeft},
     {repl = {p1, p2, q1, q2} /.
        Equal[lhs_, ___, rhs_] :> lhs -> rhs;
      (eqn1 = Inactive[D][
           Inactive[Integrate][integrand, var], var] ==
          Inactive[D][omf /. repl, var]) //
       TraditionalForm, SpanFromLeft},
     {"\nEvaluating and simplifying,", SpanFromLeft},
     {(eqn2 = Simplify[eqn1 /. repl // Activate, q1[[-1]] != 0]) //
       TraditionalForm, SpanFromLeft},
     {StringForm["\nEquating coefficients of ``:", var],
      SpanFromLeft},
     {(sys = Thread[CoefficientList[
            SubtractSides[eqn2][[1]], var] == 0]) //
       TraditionalForm, SpanFromLeft},
     {"\nSolving this system of equations,", SpanFromLeft},
     {(coef = Solve[sys, Join[aCoef, bCoef]][[1]]) //
       TraditionalForm, SpanFromLeft}, {},
     {Inactive[Integrate][integrand, var] ==
       (omf /. repl /. coef) ==
       (sol = Activate[omf /. repl /. coef]), SpanFromLeft}} //
    Grid[#, Alignment -> Left] &];
  sol]
```

Example:

```
om = Ostrogradski[(1 - 2 x - 12 x^2 + 2 x^3 - x^4 + 3 x^5)/(-1 + x^3)^2]
```

[image]

```
(* (3 - x + x^2)/(-1 + x^3) + Log[-1 + x^3] *)
```

Comment: I wish I was allowed to give two accepts. I appreciate this update.